# Permissions, apps running and backcompatibility in android 6.0 vs 4.2

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-compatibility

I have a problem and I really don't know how to solve it. It is about an application running on an Android tablet.

The application has to:

- Check if a given third party application is running AND on foreground (active);
- Install .apk files (i.e. launching them from a temp folder);
- Delete the same .apk files;
- Run on old tablets with Android down to 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich) as well as on new tablets with Android 6.0 (Marshmallow).

The problem comes from the change in *permission protocol* between API level 22 and 23. I don't see how to request permissions at run time since `requestPermissions()` was added in level 24. So I supposed I could grant permission manually before launching the application but I cannot find how (if it is even possible).

At present time, I call `UsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats()` and, as expected, it returns an empty list (using my Marshmallow tablet).

If someone could help me, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: You might want to read [the documentation on runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), which shows you how to work with runtime permissions using the support library, which will work back to API Level 15.

Comment: `android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` symbol not found... What should I do? I'm a little lost in space!

Comment: `ActivityCompat` [has had `requestPermissions()` since version `24.1.0`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)), ~2 years ago. Make sure that you are using a current edition of the support libraries (the latest as of today is 27.0.2). Make sure that you are providing the correct parameters to the method.

Comment: Compile SDK _API27_, Build Tools Version _27.0.2_, dependencies: _libs/android-support-v4.jar_, _com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2_, _com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2_. Still the same problem.

Comment: Start by getting rid of `libs/android-support-v4.jar`.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried before I saw your answer. It works. Thanks!